# find all paths from source to destinations and then calculate the path with minimum cost

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I am trying to solve one problem. Please refer complete problem statement before proceeding.

> You are given a road network, with N cities and M bi-directional
> roads. Each road has some positive amount of tax associated to
> it,meaning if there is a road connecting cities A and B with tax C,
> you will need to pay C rupees to the government every time when you
> use this road.
>
> but you have a wildcard which can be used at most K times and when you
> use wildcard while using a road, you do not need to pay tax associated
> with the road.
>
> You are planning to visit one city this weekend, due to limited budged
> you want to estimate minimum passible cost from you home-city to every
> other city, so that you can choose the destination according to the
> budget, your home-city is a city numbered with 1.

For solving above problem I am Following this approach. Step 1) Calculate all the path between vertices u,v. Step 2) For a Path p=[i-j-k-l] do following

```
   for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
           int weight=findEdgeWithMaxWeight(p);
     cost of path p=cost of path-weight;
    }
```

I am repeating this step2 for all the paths for u,v and at last I am choosing the path with minimum weight. As my answer.

Consider following diagram to visualize my approach.

[image]

But problem with above approach is that I am have to calulate all the path between u,v to get the answer. Is there any way to get the optimal path with out calculating all the paths?

Edit: Hope Problem is bit clearer now.

Comment: Please cite the original source of the problem in the question.  You [must always properly credit all copied or quoted material](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/102490/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/54065515/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: The problem statement appears to have been copied from another source: https://discuss.codechef.com/t/weekend-planning/21612.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is a Dijkstra variant with the following DP-Relaxation:
The distance array will be 2-dimensional array for which $Dist[i][j]$ is the shortest path from the source to the city $i$ using $j$ wildcards.
When processing a vertex $i$, for an incident edge $e\{i, j\}$ with cost $c$ we update as following:(for all values of k)
$Dist[j][k] = min(Dist[j][k], Dist[i][k] + C)$ 
$Dist[j][k] = min(Dist[j][k], Dist[i][k-1])$
The correctness follows from the fact that we are trying all placements of the wildcards and keeping the so-far-optimal.
The runtime is the usual Dijkstra runtime multiplied by the $K$ factor in the relaxation i.e. $O((e+n\log(n))k)$ using Fibonacci Heaps.

Comment: Dist[j][k]=min(Dist[j][k],Dist[i][k]+C)??? you are calculating Dist[j][k] with the help of Dist[j][k] itself? I mean is it correct?

Comment: What  exactly is happening? Are you running dijkstra K time from 1 to K and updaing the matrix as per the above equation? And please confirm "Dist[j][k]=min(Dist[j][k],Dist[i][k]+C)" this equation.

Comment: The equation means update dist[i][k] if the new value is smaller

Comment: You can consider it as K dijkstras but they all run at the same time so you calculate for each node how much does it cost to reach that node starting from the source and using k cards which is coming to some previous node using k cards and then coming to this one paying for the edge or comig to the previous one using k-1 cards and using one addition card for the edge

Comment: The second equation d[j][k+1]=min( d[j][k], d[i][k-1]) should not it be d[j][k] instead of  d[j][k+1] ???

Comment: oh yes, sorry my mistake